# Squish Jenkins plugin returning 0 while tests fail

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, squish

Failing tests resulted in green balls in our "Open Blue Ocean" pipeline overview. When I read the manual (https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rg-cmdline.html) this is according to specification, but using the `--exitCodeOnFail` should result in our desired behavior. In our Jenkinsfile we scripted the following:

```
squish([extraOptions: """--tags
${tag}

--retry
2

--config
addAppPath
${squishsrcdir}

--config
addAUT
startSimProApp.bat
${squishsrcdir}

--exitCodeOnFail
-666

--config
setResponseTimeout
30""", squishPackageName: 'squish for qt 6.5.2', testSuite: "${squishsrcdir}", unstableBuildOnError: true])
```

Unfortunately this results in the following error:

```
com.froglogic.squish.SquishException: unknown option --exitCodeOnFail
```

The squish plug-in version is: 8.1.1

What are my options to get red balls when a test fails under squish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--exitCodeOnFail` option is not supported by the Squish plugin.
Take a look at https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/ao-hudson.html#ao-jenkins-example-pipeline-jobs

The `squish` step sets neither build nor stage result. It returns the execution results as a string instead. Your pipeline may act based on the returned value. You can find an example on the last screenshot in the linked above chapter.

Answer (score 0):

Squish has a known issue (reported and expected to be solved) in matching returned Squish test suite execution status with retries with the final result of the job. For example, if your test fails during first retry and get passed in the next retry, the final status of the job will remain as unstable/failed.